# Ajax syntax : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am getting this

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier error

, Why ? I think i have used the syntax properly ?

```
// I've revised it
var json;
json = '{"1438905600":0,"1438992000":0}';
setTimeout( $('#example-heatmap').each(function() {
    if( json != null ){
    var obj = $.parseJSON(json);
    var now = new Date();
    new CalHeatMap().init({
      data: obj,
      start: new Date(2016, 0),
      cellSize: 11,
      range: 9,
      domain: 'month',
      domainLabelFormat: '%Y-%m',
      itemSelector: '#example-heatmap',
      legend: [1, 3, 5, 7],
      legendColors: {
        min: '#efefef',
        max: 'steelblue',
        empty: '#efefef'
      },
          tooltip: true
      //start: new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth() - 9)
    });
    } else {
        setTimeout( arguments.callee, 100 );
    }
}));
```

Comment: You have this in a `script` tag in your HTML, right? Not in a separate JavaScript file?

Comment: Surely the error points out which line the error is on - because the code you posted does not produce that error at all

Comment: Sorry, I've revised it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing a call to `jQuery#each` into `setTimeout`, but `setTimeout` expects a function or a string containing a JavaScript code block. `jQuery#each` returns neither.

The value returned is being converted to the string `[object Object]` and this is what's causing the syntax error.

To fix this, create a lambda function to contain your call to `jQuery#each`:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#example-heatmap').each(function() {
        if (json != null) {
            var obj = $.parseJSON(json);
            var now = new Date();
            new CalHeatMap().init({
                data: obj,
                start: new Date(2016, 0),
                cellSize: 11,
                range: 9,
                domain: 'month',
                domainLabelFormat: '%Y-%m',
                itemSelector: '#example-heatmap',
                legend: [1, 3, 5, 7],
                legendColors: {
                    min: '#efefef',
                    max: 'steelblue',
                    empty: '#efefef'
                },
                tooltip: true
                    //start: new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth() - 9)
            });
        } else {
            setTimeout(arguments.callee, 100);
        }
    });
});
```

I must say, however, that what you are doing looks very hacky. You're using `arguments.callee`, which is now deprecated, apparently in some attempt to "wait" on an asynchronous operation. You should instead handle the asynchrony properly, using callbacks or promises.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanations.

Answer (score 1):

I think your `.replace()` is not correct.

```
var tmp = content.replace('<![CDATA[').replace(']]>');
```

`.replace()` expects `searchvalue` and `newvalue` as given on [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp)

```
string.replace(searchvalue,newvalue)
```

Comment: That is probably a problem, but not having the second argument would not lead to a syntax error.

Comment: @JLRishe  yes ... it won't but I can't find any other problem with that code.

Comment: Sorry, I've revised it.

Comment: @syui could you check the console for line no, where the error is occuring